# Reading parquet stored in dbfs with pyspark on databricks don't work

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, parquet

i am trying to read a parquet file that is stored on dbfs, with pyspark. But i get the following error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.io.Serializable is not annotated
> with SQLUserDefinedType nor registered with UDTRegistration.}

The parquet file is extracted from a zip file an stored on dbfs. This is done by the following function:

```
def loading_zip(file_name, dest_file):
    temp_folder_write = f"/dbfs/mnt/.../{dest_file}"
    temp_folder_read = f"dbfs:/mnt/.../{dest_file}"
    with ZipFile(file_name, "r") as zipObj:
        zipObj.extractall(dest_file)
    df = spark.read.parquet(temp_folder_read)
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extract the zipped parquet files before reading. Just `spark.read.parquet(f"dbfs:/mnt/.../{dest_file}")` would be enough

Comment: thank you for quick answer, but now i get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta.exceptions' ->using the zip file with the command like you mentioned.

Comment: Are you reading delta tables by accessing dbfs directly?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. I have do define a schema like:

```
example_schema = StructType([StructField(..),..])
df_spark = spark.read.schema(example_schema).parquet("<path>")
```